# parseInt return NaN when take value from input box

Tags: javascript, html, button, input, parseint

i am trying to add 2 number as value from input form. typeof(parseInt(value1)) and typeof(parseInt(value2)) return number
but parseInt(value1)+parseInt(value2) return NaN. please someone explain

```js
var input1 = document.getElementById('num1')
var input2 = document.getElementById('num2')
var value1 = input1.value
var value2 = input2.value
btn.addEventListener('click', myfunc)
function myfunc() {
    
    alert(typeof(parseInt(value1)))
    alert(typeof(parseInt(value2)))
    alert(parseInt(value1)+parseInt(value2))
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Tính toán</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form action="">
      <div>
        <label for="num1">Number 1</label>
        <div>
          <input type="number" name="num1" id="num1" />
          <span class="error" id="errNum1">(*)</span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div>
        <label for="num2">Number 2</label>
        <div>
          <input type="number" name="num2" id="num2" />
          <span class="error" id="errNum2">(*)</span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div></div>
      <div>
        <input type="button" value="Tính toán" id="btn" />
      </div>
    </form>
    <script src="js.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hint: `typeof NaN === 'number'` - hint 2: in your code, you load your variables exactly once, which is not what you want for the value, since the value changes

Answer (score 0):

You get the value of the inputs when the page is loaded, so they will always be empty. Instead you want to get the values when the button is clicked.

```
btn.addEventListener('click', myfunc)
function myfunc() {
    var input1 = document.getElementById('num1')
    var input2 = document.getElementById('num2')
    var value1 = input1.value
    var value2 = input2.value
    alert(typeof(parseInt(value1)))
    alert(typeof(parseInt(value2)))
    alert(parseInt(value1)+parseInt(value2))
}
```

Comment: thanks, it works. i wonder when will the script tag excecuted in html code could you kindly send me some document or explain it thank you@henry

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to do that:

You don't need to use parseInt() on input type= number,
just use valueAsNumber property

```js
const myForm = document.forms['my-form']

myForm.btn.onclick = evt =>
  {
  console.clear()
  console.log(typeof myForm.num1.valueAsNumber)
  console.log(typeof myForm.num2.valueAsNumber)
  console.log( myForm.num1.valueAsNumber + myForm.num2.valueAsNumber )
  }
```

```css
label
, button {
  display : block;
  margin : .3em;
  }
```

```html
<form action="" name='my-form'>
  <label>
    Number 1
    <input type="number" name="num1" value="0" >
  </label>
  <label>
    Number 2
    <input type="number" name="num2" value="0" >
  </label>

  <button name="btn" type="button"> Tính toán </button>

</form>
```